# Discuss the continuity of $f_1$ in the following problem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Define $f_1:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f_1(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$. Discuss the continuity of $f_1$.

please give a hint for the problem. I am trying to use the idea of uniform convergence but couldn't approach

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $f_1(0)=0$. And, if $x\in(0,1]$, $1-x^2\in[0,1)$ and therefore$$f_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^2\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-1}=\frac{x^2}{1-\left(1-x^2\right)}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1.$$So, $(\forall x\in[0,1]):f_1(x)=1$ and therefore $f_1$ is discontinuous.

Comment: So $f_1$ is discontinuous, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: But, $f_1(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,1]$, right? I think $f_1$ is discontinuous..

Comment: Yes! My bad. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $r\in(0,1)$ you can use Weierstrass $M$-test with geometric series. At $0$, use $x^2$ to bound. At $1$ use the series to bound.